# Switch active buttons using useState and useEffect Hooks for Buttons in JavaScript/React?

Tags: javascript, css, button, react-hooks

I am trying to write a useState() Hook, and perhaps add useEffect() to solve active state on two buttons. It is Delivery buttons that needs the first button-delivery to be active using CSS change, and if clicked on second button, PickUp, it should change CSS UI to stay active.
And yes if it is anyhow possible i want to use Hooks.

Is there any possible way to have it done on this way?

const Header = props => {

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);


function changeButtons () {
        setIsActive = (!isActive)
    
};

return (
    <Fragment>
        <header className={classes.header}>
            <div className={classes.logo} onClick={reload}>
                <div >
                    Foodzilla
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.delivery}>
                <div
                    className={isActive ? classes.deliveryAction : classes.deliveryChoice}
                    onChange={changeButtons}
                >Delivery</div>
                <div className={classes.or}>or</div>
                <div
                    className={isActive ? classes.pickUpAction : classes.pickUpChoice}
                    onChange={changeButtons}
                >Pick Up</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `setIsActive = (!isActive)` - This is not how you call a function.  Presumably you meant: `setIsActive(!isActive)`  Aside from that, it's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Once that correction is made, what doesn't work as expected in the code?

Comment: OnChange eventListener is not proper you should use onClick event listener instead

Comment: thank you for the input.
The idea was to have one ClassName active at the time.
Now when i see all said here, it may be completely wrong to solve this in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I did a mockup of what you are trying to do (I think :D).  Here is a link to the working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-mountain-68e10k?file=/src/styles.css:59-775.

The code is also below.  There is definitely some refactoring that can be done, but I wanted to at least get you started on the right path.

Quick Summary:
Blue is Cicked (takes precedence over hover and default when active).
Green is Hovered (goes back to default when outside the div).
Red is Default (if not clicked or hovered, show red).

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [isDeliveryClicked, setIsDeliveryClicked] = useState(false);
  const [isPickupClicked, setIsPickupClicked] = useState(false);
  const [isDeliveryHovered, setIsDeliveryHovered] = useState(false);
  const [isPickupHovered, setIsPickupHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.className.includes("delivery")) {
      setIsDeliveryClicked(true);
      setIsDeliveryHovered(false);
      if (isDeliveryClicked === true) {
        setIsDeliveryClicked(false);
        setIsDeliveryHovered(true)
      }
    } else if (e.target.className.includes("pickup")) {
      setIsPickupClicked(true);
      setIsPickupHovered(false);
      if (isPickupClicked === true) {
        setIsPickupClicked(false);
        setIsPickupHovered(true)
      }
    }
  };

  const handleOnMouseOver = (e) => {
    if (e.target.className.includes("delivery")) {
      setIsDeliveryHovered(true);
    } else if (e.target.className.includes("pickup")) {
      setIsPickupHovered(true);
    }
  };

  const handleOnMouseLeave = (e) => {
    if (e.target.className.includes("delivery")) {
      setIsDeliveryHovered(false);
    } else if (e.target.className.includes("pickup")) {
      setIsPickupHovered(false);
    }
  };

  const handleClassStyler = (buttonType) => {
  if (buttonType === 'delivery') {
    if (isDeliveryClicked === true) {
      return "deliveryClicked";
    } else if (isDeliveryHovered === true && isDeliveryClicked === false) {
      return "deliveryHovered";
    } else if (isDeliveryClicked === false && isDeliveryHovered === false) {
      return "delivery";
    }
  } else if (buttonType === 'pickup'){
    if (isPickupClicked === true) {
      return "pickupClicked";
    } else if (isPickupHovered === true && isPickupClicked === false) {
      return "pickupHovered";
    } else if (isPickupClicked === false && isPickupHovered === false) {
      return "pickup";
    }
  }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        onMouseOver={handleOnMouseOver}
        onMouseLeave={handleOnMouseLeave}
        onClick={handleClick}
        className={handleClassStyler('delivery)}
      >
        Delivery
      </div>
      <div
        onMouseOver={handleOnMouseOver}
        onMouseLeave={handleOnMouseLeave}
        onClick={handleClick}
        className={handlePickupClassStyler('pickup')}
      >
        Pick Up
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The CSS I used for above is:

```
.delivery {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.deliveryClicked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.deliveryHovered {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.pickup {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.pickupClicked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.pickupHovered {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: solid black 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That is indeed one great solution.
i thank you so much for the input. Im just gonna spin with the idea for a while and resolve it

Comment: If you're not wanting to toggle them individually, I can easily make it to where they're tied to the same button state

Comment: The idea was, that either one is active at the time.
And for worse i tok the approach of making that visual difference with ternary to toggle between two different classes. for each.
When i hover i wanted to have one class and then when cliked another.
Now i have 2 buttons and 4 situations because of ClassName. 
One should be active and other should not. So i guess yes same state for both.

Comment: Which class should be ````onHover```` and which should be ````onClick````?

Comment: classes.deliveryAction (should be default) & classes.pickUpAction are active. 
classes.deliveryChoice & classes.pickUpChoice are non active.
It may be that my idea is just unusual.

Comment: Just to help you get your thinking in line: 
- Start with Two Buttons (Delivery and Pickup)
- Each button is defaulted to ````pickUpAction```` and ````deliveryAction````
- Now here is where I lose you.  You want them to activate to another class on ````click```` and ````hover````?  You don't have enough classes to properly handle that?  You'd need to do 6 classes and just for a thought experiment they could be called: pickUp, pickUpClicked, pickUpHover.  The same applies to delivery.  Does this sound like what you're after?

Comment: Yes that is about right.
i can make 6 classes, no problem.
I just wanted to useState and/or useEffect to handle when only one of the two buttons was active. Or defaulted as a starting point.

Comment: @MatijaKosmac I have edited my code above and added a link to a sandbox so you can play with the buttons.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: Its great. Im gonna test it out.
i appreciate the effort AttemptedMastery

Comment: @MatijaKosmac Not a problem!  Also, I just quickly edited some code.  When you "unclick", it was going back to red but in reality, the mouse is still over the element.  Now, when you "unclick", it goes back to the hover color and works as is from there.  If this is what you're looking for, make sure to give a brother an upvote or accepted answer :D.  Also, it will give you points when you upvote and accept the answer, which will get your journey on Stack Overflow going!

Answer (score 0):

Well,
After reading all the input (which was incredibly helpful to get my logic straight) i have come with an idea and some refactoring:
However, as almost close to a solution i still need to solve my default state. And i am stuck again.
Default state should be Delivery, and the (button) should have active CSS as well.
Also, when i add CSS .deliveryChoice:hover {} it does not respond. My guess is that, as it is a child component the header don't respond as it reads no inside buttons.

Right now, they are both off.

My Header component:

```
const Header = props => {

return (
    <Fragment>
        <header className={classes.header}>
            <div className={classes.logo} onClick={reload}>
                <div >
                    Foodzilla
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.delivery}>
                <DeliveryButton
                    className={classes.deliveryChoice}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div className={classes.deliveryAdress}>
                    Delivery to:
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={classes.deliveryTime}>
                <div >
                    Choose time: Now
                </div>
            </div>

            <HeaderCartButton onClick={props.onShowCart} />
        </header>
        <div className={classes['main-image']}>
            <img src={mealsImg} />
        </div>
    </Fragment>
```

And my DeliveryButton:

```
const deliveryChoice = [{ name: 'Delivery' }, { name: 'PickUp' }]
const DeliveryButton = () => {
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
return deliveryChoice.map((data, k) => (
    <div
        key={k}
        className={`deliveryChoice ${active === k ? 
          classes.deliveryAction : ''}`}
        onClick={() => setActive(k)}
    >
        {data.name}
    </div>
));
};
```

And CSS for the Button:

```
.deliveryChoice {
}
.deliveryAction {
background-color: #ffffff;
border-color: #ffffff;
display: flex;
font-size: 13px;
justify-content: space-around;
width: 4rem;
height: 1.8rem;
cursor: pointer;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
align-items: center;
border-radius: 20px;
/* padding-left: 0.5rem; */
}
```